# How can I connect .NET Core application to wsdl service

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core

Before .NET Core, I added a link to the wsdl service and a class appeared in my application with which I could extract data. And how to do it in .NET Core?

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same way.

1. `Install-Package System.ServiceModel.Http` (client library also supports TCP)
2. Right click on the project item in Solution Explorer -> Add -> Connected Service:

[image]

3. Click "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider" under "Other services":

[image]

4. The rest of steps are the same. Type WSDL location and click "Go", and so on:

[image]

.NET WCF Client on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf